# How to add a dot to a raw man file at the end of a line?

Tags: man, groff, roff

I've got a fragment of a manual file which looks like this:

```
.TP
.I krb5_key_file
Location of the key for this client's principal.
Note that the key file must be owned by root and mode 0400.
The default is
.I /etc/audit/audit.key
```

I would like to add an unformatted dot (`.`) at the end of this fragment.

1. Adding a dot at the end of the last line like this

   ```
   [...]
   .I /etc/audit/audit.key.
   ```

   doesn't work because the dot is being underlined.
2. Adding an escaped dot in a new line

   ```
   [...]
   .I /etc/audit/audit.key
   \[char46]
   ```

   doesn't work as well because a space character is inserted between `/etc/audit/audit.key` and the dot: `/etc/audit/audit.key .`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Somehow related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469341/escaping-dots-in-groff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of 2-character macros that let you format their arguments in two different fonts, alternating between them. In your case, you'd use the [.IR](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Man-font-macros.html) macro.  R means Roman, the default font.

```
The default is 
.IR /etc/audit/audit.key .
```

Comment: This one seems to be much cleaner than the solution by Stephen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alternative method of setting italics/underline mode:  `\fI`.  Then `\fP` to return to previous font:

So you would have

```
\fI/etc/audit/audit.key\fP.
```

Comment: FWIW, you can also use `\fB` for bold in the same way

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to do it like this:

```
The default is \fI/etc/audit/audit.key\fP.
```